# Not able to import views in django, but it works in django shell

Tags: python, django

I have the following simple urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from base import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test$', 'views.test', name='test'),
)
```

And the following basic view:
from django.shortcuts import render

```
def test(request):
    return render(request, "base/test.html")
```

I have a project named blog and an app named base.

I know i can fix this by using "base.views.test" in the urls.py but in theory this should be working i think because there is a **init**.py file in the base directory.

When using views.test im getting "no module named views" as an error in django but when i do this in the django shell it works:

```
 from base import views
 views.test
 function test
```

I'm wondering why this works in the django shell and not in django itself. No matter what im doing in django, except from using the full absolute path to the view im getting an error saying that i couldnt find a module named views..so basically im looking for an explaination of why its not working, not a solution since i know i could be using the full path to the view and make it work.

Ive seen other threads on stackoverflow where a user has the same problem but only a solution is provided, no explaination..they only tell people to use the full path to the view but i dont really understand why it wouldnt work doing it like that.. i know i also could be doing it this way:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('base',
    url(r'^test$', 'views.test', name='test'),
)
```

but im trying to understand why it isnt working when using "from base import views" since it thought this would be working since its working with other regular python modules.

File structure:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── base
│   │       └── test.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

New traceback when adding (views.test without quotes, remove the old traceback to avoid the post to get too long and unreadable):

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/test

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.7
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  69.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  551.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  440.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  319.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  347.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  342.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/lib/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/Users/exceed/code/python/django/blog/blog/urls.py" in <module>
  8.     url(r'^test$', views.test, name='test'),

Exception Type: NameError at /test
Exception Value: name 'views' is not defined
```

Comment: Show please your file structure. Also you say that there is `init.py` in base directory, double-check its name, it should be `__init__.py`. You can add traceback of error to your post, that will be helpful

Comment: updated..yes the init is actually created by django so it should be correct anyway and its with the double underscores..ill add the traceback..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your view function instead of string with dot path to it:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from base import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test$', views.test, name='test'),
)
```

Quick explanation: you can pass into 2nd parameter of `url` either a function or a string with dotted path to it. When it's a function, django will simply call it when url is opened, when it's a dotted path: django will search for that function in your `PYTHONPATH`. It doesn't matter if you import your module inside your `urls.py`, django will always search in `PYTHONPATH`. You can additionally pass prefix into first argument of patterns, and all functions given by dotted path string will be searched relative to that prefix.

So if you don't want to pass prefix into `patterns` (because for example you are using multiple apps and only one `patterns`, the only solution here is to pass functions instead of dotted paths. You can additionally use multiple `patterns` (and specify different prefixes in each of them) and then include them into main `patterns` (without prefix passed into it).

Comment: You don't need the 'base' prefix in the patterns call.

Comment: @GwynBleidD I did write in my original post that i did not want to do that even though i do thinks its a good solution..i want to know why my code doesnt work, not an alternative solution

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: i didnt think that either but it doesnt work without it and i dont understand why it doesnt work without..i updated original post with the traceback

Comment: Fixed answer. I've copied wrong code from your question. Now it's without `base` prefix in patterns.

Comment: When i remove the quotes from the views.test in the url function im getting another error instead: "name 'views' is not defined" even though i have the import  ..i did try this earlier and it didnt work which i think is a little wierd

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't happen if you definitely have the import at the top. Please update your question to add the full edited version of the file, and the full traceback you get.

Comment: Added quick explanation why solution with quotes won't work without prefix passed into patterns.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the new traceback. Hmm ok, it adds it to the pythonpath, but then it should at least work without quotation marks..then it should honor the import i think

Comment: Ah, i did work when adding the import..i dont know why but when i opening the file again now it did not have the import any longer..added it and it works when removing quotation.. thanks :)